# Extract milliseconds from datetimeobject

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have timestamp like this, 1581584236812954845 and i tried to extract milliseconds alone

```
df['time'] =pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['time'] =df['time'].dt.strftime(("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") [:-3])
```

But i only got 08:57:16. At the end i want output as 0.812 from 08:57:16.812954845

Comment: no it throws error.

Comment: added an answer to clarify...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the [str accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html):

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([1581584236812954845]))

s.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").str[:-3]
# or simpler: s.astype(str).str[:-3]
0    2020-02-13 08:57:16.812
dtype: object
```

Side note: in your code,

```
("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
Out[54]: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

...is why you get e.g. `08:57:16`. I suggest having another look at where exactly to place which bracket.

Comment: df['time'] =df['time'].dt.strftime(("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").str[:-3])  throws error

Comment: @priya: of course it does, because the syntax is invalid. please have another look at my answer.